# Impossible to upload image to Google play store

Tags: google-play

I can't upload images to the Google Play store in order to put my app in production.

None of the images can be uploaded, I checked 50 times, the size is good and I tried as png, jpg, jpeg, etc without success.

Here are the screenshots of my tries:

[image]
[image]
[image]

What could be wrong?

Edit: I have the same problem to upload the apk and the problem seems to come from CORS policy but deactivate it does not change anything...

Comment: Any news about what went wrong?

Comment: Nope unfortunately, it still does not work. App upload does not work either. I had to use a friend's computer with Google Chrome in private mode to make it work

Comment: The problem still remains, unsolved, tedious

Comment: I have the same issue right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution until November 2, 2020 is to use the classic Google Play Console in private mode. There, image uploading is working as intended.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you really saved my day! I wrote to the support hope that it will work back soon. Please let me know if you have some news insights

Comment: Note that I had to uncheck "use by default the new console" in my settings in order to be able to switch to the classic version otherwise I had a 403 error page